# Self-joins in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server

```
Type  Status    date                       ID           Users
-------------------------------------------------------------
  2       1     6/1/2015 8:43:13.557 AM    1140914474   2B 4E
  1       1     6/1/2015 8:43:40.057 AM    1140914474   2B 4E
  2       1     6/1/2015 12:29:15.093 PM    655666666   2B 4E
  1       1     6/1/2015 12:32:43.067 PM    655666666   2B 4E
  2       1     6/1/2015 6:02:30.557 PM    1694543676   2B 4E
  1       1     6/1/2015 6:14:34.180 PM    1694543676   2B 4E
```

I need to get date difference between row Type 2 and Type 1, and sum all that time by days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query for your question it will be bellow:

```
select 
  datea,
  sum(differenceSec) as Total
from (
select a.type,
  cast(a.date as date) datea,
  cast(b.date as date) dateb,
  DATEDIFF ( ss , a.date , b.date ) as differenceSec
from data a
  inner join data b
    on b.id = a.id
      and b.type = 1
  where a.type = 2 ) result
 group  by datea
```

The first part of query, group by day the result and sum them. And in the subquery we obtain the difference between type 2 and type 1.

The difference are in seconds, but you can change it for you want.

Here you find an example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/600f9/24 with your data.

The first part of query group by day the result and sum its. And in the subquery we obtain the difference between type 2 and type 1.

Comment: Thank you for your help I did finally one script.It is working but i have still al loot to work on it.This is how it looks

Comment: SELECT CardNo, BikeId, StartDate, Timp, DATEDIFF(mi, StartDate, Timp) as Utilizat FROM (SELECT CardNo, BikeId, StartDate, (SELECT MIN(TransferDate) FROM [Transaction] b WHERE b.BikeId = a.BikeId AND b.CardNo= CardNo AND b.StartDate > a.TransferDate ) AS TimpFROM [Transaction] a WHERE MONTH(StartDate) = '11' and ([Type] = 1 or [Type] = 2) and year(StartDate) = '2015' and FinalGateFulfillmentStatus = '2' and CardId = a.CardId and BikeId is not null ) AS c

Comment: I'm sure there is a loot more to work on it because i found all ready some glitches :( and i still have to find how to sum by day's.But thank you all again and all help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The same, as for SQL Server 2005 :-) This query will return all data you want to aggregate

```
select 
    cast(b.date as date) day, 
    datediff(s, a.date, b.date) diff 
from 
    mytable a 
join 
    mytable b on a.ID = b.ID 
where 
    a.Type = 2 and b.Type = 1
```

Use this query as CTE:

```
with result as 
( 
     select 
         cast(b.date as date) dt, 
         datediff(s, a.date, b.date) diff 
     from
         mytable a 
     join 
         mytable b on a.ID = b.ID 
     where 
         a.Type = 2 and b.Type = 1
)
select 
    dt, sum(diff) difftotal  
from 
    result  
group by 
    dt;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help I did finally one script.It is working but i have still al loot to work on it.This is how it looks:

Comment: SELECT  CardNo,
     BikeId,
     StartDate,
     Timp,
     DATEDIFF(mi, StartDate, Timp) as Utilizat
FROM  (SELECT CardNo,
 BikeId,
 StartDate,
(SELECT  MIN(TransferDate)
FROM   [Transaction] b
WHERE  b.BikeId = a.BikeId
AND    b.CardNo= CardNo
AND    b.StartDate > a.TransferDate
 ) AS TimpFROM    [Transaction] a
WHERE   MONTH(StartDate) = '11'
and ([Type] = 1 or [Type] = 2)
and    year(StartDate) = '2015'
and    FinalGateFulfillmentStatus = '2' 
and    CardId = a.CardId 
and    BikeId is not null
 ) AS c

Comment: I'm sure there is a loot more to work on it because i found all ready some glitches :( and i still have to find how to sum by day's.But thank you all again and all help is appreciated